# How to read the messages from kafka which are already committed

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, confluent-platform

I have requirement in kafka,  want to read the messages from kafka which are already committed  instead of all messages

Comment: What does your code look like so far? Which client are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With spring-kafka, implement `ConsumerSeekAware` and you can seek to any offset you like during startup.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#seek).